# Microsoft Graph API, how to read write Groups File Share as Guest Account from another domain?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I have two domains and one account under each domain, "user1@aaa.com" and "user2@bbb.com".

- user1@aaa.com create a Office365 Group "SharedGroup",
- user2@bbb.com is invited to the "SharedGroup" across domain as Guest User,
- user2@bbb.com receives the email that it has joined the "SharedGroup" and is able to access any of the shared file in the group via Sharepoint WebUI https://aaa.sharepoint.com/sites/...,

As user1@aaa.com, Microsoft Graph API can read/write files under "SharedGroup" just as API doc says.

However, as user2@bbb.com, API accessing "SharedGroup" using following API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group id>/drive/root/children
```

(I got the Group ID by login as user1@aaa.com)

returns unauthenticated error, with the URI correctly returned,

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "unauthenticated",
        "message": "Invalid audience Uri 'https://aaa.sharepoint.com/'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "5f1c1e32-fce1-4bb8-986a-92067cdd32d9",
            "date": "2018-10-29T22:47:13"
        }
    }
}
```

*How do I read/write shared files from Groups as Guest Account from another domain using Graph API? or any API?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you include your authentication code?  I'd guess you're authenticating against the /common endpoint instead of a tenanted endpoint, but guests need to be authenticated against the tenanted endpoint in order to access resources in the tenant they've been invited to.

Comment: Access token (JWT) contains "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/", I just re-queried the same today, and got a different result.
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource is not found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "db0cb9d2-18f9-4a62-822a-4d5a08807af7",
      "date": "2018-10-30T17:55:10"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I also created an Access Token contain "aud": "https://<user company domain>.sharepoint.com", API call to "https://<user company domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site name>/_api/lists" returned Sharepoint objects. However, if I create an Access Token contain "aud": "https://<guest user company domain>.sharepoint.com", API call to "https://<guest user company domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site name>/_api/lists" returned {"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}.

Comment: What endpoint are you using to authenticate the user?  It looks like you're using something like https://login.microsoftonline.com/common, but to force the guest (user2@bbb.com) you'd need to use something like https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaa.onmicrosoft.com so that you get a token for user2@bbb.com in the context of the AAA tenant.

Comment: Nice! that's was the issue, once I login with login.microsoftonline/aaa.onmicrosoft.com, the access token works now.